# When running ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, appdata

when I try to run Ionic, it gives this error, thank you for your help.

Indeed, the AppData file has also been deleted !!

'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most probably indicates that Ionic is not installed.

Try to open a terminal and type:

```
ionic --version
```

If it gives an error, that means you should install ionic.
To install it, open the terminal and type:

```
npm install -g ionic
```